# How to get id from foreign key model in django

Tags: django, python-3.6

How Do I get id of to_user from the below model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
     status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     from_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'from_user')
     to_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="to_user")
     date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
     date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

     def create(self,request, **kwargs, ):
         friend = self.create(from_user_id=request.user.id, status="Pending")
         return friend

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('from_user', 'to_user'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_user.email
```

my view :

```
def accept_friend_request(request, uidb64, status):
     """Accept button will lead to entry in database as accepted and reject button will lead to entry in database as rejected  based on status flag"""
      Friend.status = "pending"
      try:
         uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
         friend_user = User.objects.filter(id=Friend.to_user.id)
         f = Friend.objects.filter(friend_id = friend_user)
         if f:
             f.status=status
             f.save()
             f.status = "accepted"
            return render(request, 'users/friend_list.html', {"uidb64": uid, "status": status})
          else:
             f.status = "rejected"
             f.save()
             return render(request, 'users/friend_list.html', {'uidb64':uid, 'status':status})
      except AttributeError:
          return render(request, 'blog/base.html')
```

I cannot retrieve the friend_user = User.objects.filter(id=Friend.to_user.id)

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

`Friend` is a model class, and you need an instance of such class in order to relate it to another model instance as a foreign relationship.

For example:

```
friend_instance = Friend.objects.get(name='Madeleaine')
...
friend_user = friend_instance.to_user.id
```